# Compare BCrypt hash to Bcrypt hash PHP

Tags: php, security, hash, passwords, bcrypt

here's what I'm up against.

I have an app for iPhone that I am building that communicates with password protected pages on my site. The app can get through the password protection fine and can get the response from the page just fine. The problem is that when I try to login to the site from my app it gets rejected. I believe this is because I am hashing  the password with Bcrypt in the app before sending it to the site and then checking it with `password_verify()`, which of course takes the plain text of the password and then the hashed version, but I am giving it two hashed versions of the same thing which it is not accepting.

My question is this: is it possible to compare the two encrypted passwords using `password_verify` or some other function, or not? And if not, is it secure enough to (dare I say it) send the password in plain text from the app?

Thanks to everyone in advance!

Answer (score 2):

> is it possible to compare the two encrypted passwords using password_verify or some other function, or not?

No. `password_verify` *requires* the plaintext password and the previously hashed form of the password with the embedded salt as its inputs and there's no way around that. The algorithm is such that you need the salt again to produce the same hash, so your only other option would be to transfer the hash/salt to the client to reproduce the algorithm there. But that's pointless, since you want to do the password confirmation at the server, not on the untrustworthy client.

> And if not, is it secure enough to (dare I say it) send the password in plain text from the app?

Sure, as long as the *communication channel* is secure, meaning you have an SSL connection.